# Flexbox и умное выравнивание

Tags: css

Вот пример разметки: http://jsfiddle.net/vmesxm0e/

```
<div class = "wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

.wrap {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
.wrap div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Идея в следующем: объекты внутри должны помещаться в строку ровно по 5 штук, причем, если их меньше, то они должны выравниваться по левому краю, а не по ширине. Можно такое сделать без Java Script?

P.S. Через Flexbox делается не в целях масштабирования, а чтобы не высчитывать margin от каждого блока для их выравнивания по ширине. Если есть другой способ, то тоже рад о нем узнать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ширина элементов фиксированная? Ширина контейнера фиксированная? Вот пример. Уточните задачу в комментариях.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrap div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.wrap div:nth-child(5n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```